# Text-to-speech using Phonics Sounds

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, text-to-speech, sapi

How can I get the phonics sound by pushing any letter key? For example, I want to get the phonics sound of `A` by pushing the 'A' key.

I'm using Microsoft SAPI v5.1. Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: No........please Help me I want to get the phonics sound...not a normal alphabet sound

Comment: Not sure I understand when you hit A key, what sound do you expect? What do you mean phonics sound?

Answer (score 4):

Add reference to `System.Speech` assembly.

Add `using System.Speech.Synthesis;`

```
using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    speechSynthesizer.Speak("A");
    speechSynthesizer.Speak("B");
    speechSynthesizer.Speak("C");
}
```

For example like this:

```
using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    while (true)
    {
        var consoleKey = Console.ReadKey();
        if (consoleKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            break;
        var text = consoleKey.KeyChar.ToString();
        speechSynthesizer.Speak(text);
    }
}
```